# How can I study the monotonicity of the following sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$b_{n} = \frac{n^2}{2n + 1},$$

My problem is in the term $n^2$ Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you try to solve $b_{n+1}\ge b_n$?

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 1):

Let's step to the continous case for a while. Consider $f: (0,+\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{2x+1}$. This function is differentiable, and we have:

$$
f'(x) = \frac{2x(2x+1) - 2x^2}{(2x+1)^2} = \frac{2x^2+1}{(2x+1)^2}
$$

Therefore, $f'(x) > 0$, for all $x > 0$. This implies that $f$ is increasing. In particular, $b_n = f(n) < f(n+1) = b_{n+1}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

HinT: we have $$b_{n+1}-b_n=\frac{2n^2+4n+1}{(2n+3)(2n+1)}>0$$